# how to read the OTP sent to mobile automatically using python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to automate the User login process using selenium for a website which has 2 Factor authentication.

I have already built the code using python and selenium webdriver to add the username and password. once the one step verification is done the website sent a OTP to the registered mobile.
I need to read the OTP from mobile and add in the code to login into the website.

So, any help or guidance will be helpful to achieve the above case? Is there any API or any python code to read the OTP from mobile?

Comment: Provide more info, code screenshots, and what's OTP?

Comment: @miramarska - I am trying to do the 2 factor authentication using python and selenium in a website. So the process is when i provide my username and password the website send for the OTP to the registered mobile whenever i try to login the website. So i am trying to do this using selenium . I need help on automating this task.

Comment: You haven't explained much, please do post screenshots and code.
Also, I'm not sure how you'd use Selenium to extract token from a mobile app, Selenium doesn't do that.